# check if a file is currently being included at process time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm wondering whether it's possible to distribute a C library as a single file where different parts of the file in question are expressed depending on the file is being used. This question is inspired by the `GenericList.inc` example on the Free Pascal Wiki [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Templates) (warning: no https) and the list of single file C and C++ libraries [here](https://github.com/nothings/single_file_libs), which does not appear to have any single file libraries specifically for C. There are many libraries there that are written in C++ using only a C-comaptible API though.

For example, a very simple library with one useless function `add` might look like this:

```
/* foo.h */
int add(int x, int y);
```

and the other file

```
/* foo.c */
#include "foo.h"

int add(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}
```

If there was a magical preprocessor variable `AM_I_BEING_SOURCED`, we could combine it into a single file for ease of distribution.

The idea here is that `AM_I_BEING_SOURCED` is false when the file in question is the "root" of the current arboresence of files being included and true otherwise.

```
/* strawman.c */
int add(int x, int y);

#ifndef AM_I_BEING_SOURCED

int add(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

#endif
```

Is there a way to fake/emulate `AM_I_BEING_SOURCED` that doesn't rely on an absurd hack like line number arithmetic, for example?

Is there a way to fake/emulate `AM_I_BEING_SOURCED` that *does* rely on an absurd hack?

Comment: Header only libraries are popular for C++ because of how templates work. For C, it's easier to just use one header and one source file (Possibly built from multiple master source files; see sqlite for an example) for easy embedding into projects.

Comment: You can just call the preprocessor directly and produce an output file with all the headers included.

Comment: Note that a generic name such as `AM_I_BEING_SOURCED` becomes creaky as soon as you have two or more such libraries (sets of functions).  Is it that they are all being sourced or none are being sourced, or can you source some and not others?  Your name is an 'all or none' solution.  It isn't clear that's what's wanted.

Comment: Much the simplest solution is to build a library with separate object files for each set of functions (or even each function). Then let the linker do the selection of what's needed and what's not. It's old fashioned, perhaps, but it does work with static libraries. With shared libraries, the equation is more complex — you get all the functions in the library available to the programs. A dubious alternative is for the program using the library to identify which functions it calls (`#define USE_FUNCTION_ABCDEF`, `#define USE_FUNCTION_PQRSTU`, etc), and then have the library compile what it must.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `AM_I_BEING_SOURCED` is intended to be a hypothetical preprocessor feature that doesn't exist, not an ordinary variable that I'm using in an odd way.